# What does it mean physically to set $\exp(ikr)=1$ in the dipole approximation?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-electrodynamics, dipole-moment

In the dipole approximation one sets the $exp(ikr)=1+ik.r+...=1$.
($|<f|exp(ikr)\epsilon.r|i>|^2$). Which makes $k.r=0$.

What does it mean physically? Is the plane transverse wave converted to longitudinal?

$k.r=0$ -> the polarization $\epsilon$ (or electric field $E$) is parallel to $k$ ?

Answer (score 3):

It comes about by assuming that the wavelength ($\sim k^{-1}$) is much larger than the typical atomic length scales ($r$).

Comment: Thanks. But is k.r = 0, true for longitudinal DC E field or not ?

Comment: @Anonymous That's the wrong conclusion. Just because the scalar product is close to zero doesn't mean k and r are orthogonal. For example, if k||r, and k~=0, then k.r is also zero.